# C++ boost de-serialization throws up error

Tags: c++, boost

Error :
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
Aborted (core dumped)

Message.h :

```
/*
    GameInit.cpp 
    Created by :
    Divyanshu Rathi
    5/09/2014
*/

#ifndef __GAMEINIT_H_INCLUDED__  
#define __GAMEINIT_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>




#include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>



using namespace std;


extern bool isturncompleted[5];
extern int whichplayerturn;
extern int startlocationno;
extern int kplane;
extern float jplane;
extern bool showplanetransition;
extern int playerwhocanbuy;
extern int whichplayeristhis;

class City
{
public:

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & *name;
        ar & group;
        ar & cost;
        ar & mortagecost;
        ar & house1cost;
        ar & house2cost;
        ar & house3cost;
        ar & house4cost;
        ar & rent0;
        ar & rent1;
        ar & rent2;
        ar & rent3;
        ar & rent4;
        ar & renthotel;
        ar & isbought;
        ar & boughtby;
        ar & totalhouses;
        ar & ishotel;
    }

    string* name;
    int group;
    int cost;
    int mortagecost;
    int house1cost;
    int house2cost;
    int house3cost;
    int house4cost;
    int hotelcost;
    int rent0;
    int rent1;
    int rent2;
    int rent3;
    int rent4;
    int renthotel;
    int isbought;
    int boughtby;
    int totalhouses;
    int ishotel;



};

class Game
{
public:
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & startingmoney;
        ar & jailfine;
        ar & tax;
        ar & map;
        ar & totalcolorgroups;
        ar & colorcodes;

        ar & whichplayerturn;

        ar & isturncompleted;
        ar & hismoney;

        cout << "robin"<< endl;
        ar & citiesowned;

        ar & noofcitiesowned;
        ar & citiesofeachgroup;
        ar & currentlocation;

        ar & temporarylocation;

        ar & cities;
        ar & *currency;
    }

    string* currency;
    int startingmoney;
    int jailfine;
    int tax;
    vector <City> cities;
    int map[50][50];
    int totalcolorgroups;
    float colorcodes[20][3];
    int whichplayerturn=1;
    bool isturncompleted[5]={1,1,1,1,1};
    void Generatecolorgroups();

    //string *name[5];
    float hismoney[5];
    int citiesowned[5][100][5];
    int noofcitiesowned[5];
    int citiesofeachgroup[5][50];
    int currentlocation[5];
    int temporarylocation[5];




};



#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
// create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

     boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << Monopoly;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called

        Game newg;
         // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> newg;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
```

Basically it gives no problem while serializing but when deserialized it throws up that error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::ofstream ofs("filename");
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << Monopoly;

ofs.close(); // <= HERE

Game newg;
std::ifstream ifs("filename");
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
ia >> newg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question, when you write:

```
   oa << Monopoly;
    // archive and stream closed when destructors are called <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The file in not closed, when you try to open it for reading.

Add an `ofs.close()` before your reading test.  Or better, put each part of the test in a { } block with related stream variable declared inside the block, so that archive and stream gets destroyed when leaving the block scope.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.  Boost serialization gives this error when you try to deserialize a previously serialized class that has uninitialized member variables.  For your problem, you will have to initialize every variable in your class to some sensible value.

In other words,

```
...
int cost;
int mortagecost;
int house1cost;
int house2cost;
...
```

should be

```
...
int cost = 0;
int mortagecost = 0;
int house1cost = 0;
int house2cost = 0;
...
```

or you can initialize every variable of every instantiation of your class.  I hope this helps.

PS: you don't have initialize STL containers.